# UISearchController won't stay at top in the table header view

Tags: xcode, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

I'm having a problem on how to tie the UISearchController at top of my UITableHeaderView. I've tried some scenarios I found here on the forum but they didn't work. It's scrolling, and I hate it. However when is active, it stays on the top. But I'd like to be on the top when is also inactive. Share some code if you have bros.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting your UISearchController into a UITableHeaderView (which is why it's scrolling along with the table cells), add your search bar ***on top of*** the UITableView.

And if you're using a UITableViewController, please ditch that (because it doesn't play nice with views added on top of the table) and use a custom UIViewController with a table view as a subview inside of the content view.